# Order and move files into directories based on some filenames pattern

Tags: powershell, batch-file

To move files into folders I use this script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "SPLITCHAR=-"  & rem // (a single character to split the file names)
set "SEARCHSTR=_"  & rem // (a certain string to be replaced by another)
set "REPLACSTR= "  & rem // (a string to replace all found search strings)
set "OVERWRITE="   & rem // (set to non-empty value to force overwriting)

rem // Get file location and pattern from command line arguments:
set "LOCATION=%~1" & rem // (directory to move the processed files into)
set "PATTERNS=%~2" & rem // (file pattern; match all files if empty)

rem /* Prepare overwrite flag (if defined, set to character forbidden
rem    in file names; this affects later check for file existence): */
if defined OVERWRITE set "OVERWRITE=|"
rem // Continue only if target location is given:
if defined LOCATION (
    rem // Create target location (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%LOCATION%"
    rem /* Loop through all files matching the given pattern
    rem    in the current working directory: */
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "%PATTERNS%"') do (
        rem // Process each file in a sub-routine:
        call :PROCESS "%%F" "%LOCATION%" "%SPLITCHAR%" "%SEARCHSTR%" "%REPLACSTR%"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
rem // Retrieve first argument of sub-routine:
set "FILE=%~1"
rem // Split name at (first) split character and get portion in front:
for /F "delims=%~3" %%E in ("%~1") do (
    rem // Append a split character to partial name:
    set "FOLDER=%%E%~3"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Right-trim partial name:
if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4%~3=!"
set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~3=!"
rem /* Check whether partial name is not empty
rem    (could happen if name began with split character): */
if defined FOLDER (
    rem // Replace every search string with another:
    if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4=%~5!"
    rem // Create sub-directory (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    rem /* Check if target file already exists; if overwrite flag is
    rem    set (to an invalid character), the target cannot exist: */
    if not exist "%~2\!FOLDER!\!FILE!%OVERWRITE%" (
        rem // Move file finally (surpress `1 file(s) moved.` message):
        1> nul move /Y "!FILE!" "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

To use script I must

1- open cmd
2- to execute batch i have to

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\T\
"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\T\build-folder-hierarchy.bat" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\T\" "*.pdf"
```

But problem what is ?

For each .pdf file batch creates a relative folder but I don't want it creates folders in that way. Look https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRsPc.png

```
aaaa aaaa S02 [folder]
aaaa aaaa S02e01.pdf [folder]
aaaa aaaa S02e02.pdf [folder]
aaa.aaaa.aaa.aa.aaaaa.S02 [folder]
```

What I want instead ?

```
├─aaaa aaaa S02 [folder]
│ ├─aaaa aaaa S02e01.pdf[file]
│ ├─aaaa aaaa S02e02.pdf [file]
  └─ ....
├─aaa.aaaa.aaa.aa.aaaaa.S02 [folder]
│ └─aaa.aaaa.aa.aa.aaaaa.S02E13.pdf [file]
:
```

Just an example name to understand how *.pdf* files name are formatted

```
aaaaaaaaa aa aaaaa S01e12 720p Repack.pdf
aaa aaaaaaaaa S01e05 Versione 720p.pdf
aaa aaaaaaaa S01e05 Versione 1080p.pdf
aaa aaaa s2e06.pdf
aaa aaaa S03e12.pdf
aaa.aaaa.aaa.on.Earth.S02E13.pdf
aaa.aaaa.aaaa.S02E01.HDTV.x264.SUB.ITA.pdf
```

Usually pdf files name are formatted in this way [pattern]

```
s01
s01e1
s1
s1e1
s1e01
s1e01-10
```

character, like the `e` and `s` are almost always present within these patterns name
general form should be

```
sxx
sxxex
sx
sxex
sxexx
sxexx-xx
```

**X** is a number, case for letter **s** and **e** is irrilevant

Powershell solution is well accepted for answer.

Comment: Instead of a link to an image, please put your actual folder structure into your question as text!

Comment: I add actual structure made by script

Comment: I knew I have seen [that script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39529287) once before... I don't get what you actually want, because you provide multiple examples (like `aaaa aaaa S02e01.pdf`, `s01e1[.pdf]`); the script is intended to split file names at one certain character, take the part before and use that as target folder name; is there any such character, like the `e`, for example?

Comment: *take the part before and use that as target folder name?* **yes**. ***BUT*** that script is insufficent because I have different files name pattern. character, like the `e` and `s` are almost always present within these patterns name.

Comment: So basically you've got a whole bunch of, uh... single novels... in their own directories and you want to group them by, uh... book series... and you also want to replace spaces with periods to match the, uh... _standard_ way of naming them?

Comment: Also, I've found that a lot of novels come with a separate file containing publisher's notes and cover art. Is that the case on your system? (If so, do those need to be moved as well, or can they be ignored?)

Comment: Can you provide use an example of lets say 15 files and the result your are expecting (naming and structure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing. You have not *described* the format of the file names, but just show some examples and using examples instead of specifications may be misunderstood. Post code wrote for other problem that don't work on this one is certainly not useful. You did not showed an example of the input and wanted output using real file names, so it is possible that a solution based on the example data will not work on real data.

**EDIT**: *New specification added*. Both specifications and program code have been modified accordingly to a request given in comments.

Below there are the specifications of this problem as I understand they:

---

> "Given a series of *.pdf files with this format:
>
> ```
> any string hereS##Eany string here.pdf
>               / | ^-- "E" letter
>     "S" letter  digit
> ```
>
> extract the string that ends before the "E" after the "S-digit" delimiter and move the file to a folder with such a name, "S" and "E" letters are not case sensitive. Ignore files that have not the previous format."

This code solve the problem based on *such specifications*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Change current directory to the one where this .bat file is located
cd "%~P0"

set "digits=0123456789"

rem Process all *.pdf files
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (

   rem Get the folder name of this file
   call :getFolder "%%f"

   rem If this file have a properly formatted name: "headS##Etail"
   if defined folder (
      rem Move the file to such folder
      if not exist "!folder!" md "!folder!"
      move "%%f" "!folder!"
   )

)
goto :EOF


:getFolder file

set "folder="
set "file=%~1"
set "head="
set "tail=%file%"

:next
   for /F "delims=%digits%" %%a in ("%tail%") do set "head=%head%%%a"
   set "tail=!file:*%head%=!"
   if not defined tail exit /B
   if /I "%head:~-1%" equ "S" goto found
   :digit
      if "!digits:%tail:~0,1%=!" equ "%digits%" goto noDigit
      set "head=%head%%tail:~0,1%"
      set "tail=%tail:~1%"
   goto digit
   :noDigit
goto next

:found
for /F "delims=Ee" %%a in ("%tail%") do set "folder=%head%%%a"
exit /B
```

To use this Batch file, place it on the same folder where the original files are located and execute it without parameters; you may also execute it via a double-click in the explorer. Example session:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> dir /B
test.bat
The_Good_Wife_S06e15.pdf
The_Good_Wife_S06e22.pdf
TOCCO_ANGELO_4.pdf
True Blood S07e07_001.pdf
True Detective S02E03-04 Repack.pdf
True Detective S02e03.pdf
True Detective S02e03_001.pdf
True.Detective.S02e02.1080p.WEBMux.pdf
Tudors S04e08.pdf
Tutti pazzi per amore s3e15-16.pdf
Tutto Pu‗ Succedere S01e01-02.pdf
Twin Peaks s1e1-8.pdf
Twin Peaks s2e16-22.pdf
Tyrant S02e07.pdf
Tyrant.S01e01_02.720p.DLMux.pdf
Ultimo 2 - La Sfida.pdf
Ultimo 3 -L Infiltrato.pdf
Una Mamma Imperfetta S02e01-13.pdf
Under the Dome S02e02 Versione 720p.pdf
Under.the.Dome.S03E07.HDTV.x264.SUB.ITA.pdf

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> test.bat

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> tree /F
Listado de rutas de carpetas
El número de serie del volumen es 00000088 0895:160E
C:.
│   test.bat
│   TOCCO_ANGELO_4.pdf
│   Ultimo 2 - La Sfida.pdf
│   Ultimo 3 -L Infiltrato.pdf
│
├───The_Good_Wife_S06
│       The_Good_Wife_S06e15.pdf
│       The_Good_Wife_S06e22.pdf
│
├───True Blood S07
│       True Blood S07e07_001.pdf
│
├───True Detective S02
│       True Detective S02E03-04 Repack.pdf
│       True Detective S02e03.pdf
│       True Detective S02e03_001.pdf
│
├───True.Detective.S02
│       True.Detective.S02e02.1080p.WEBMux.pdf
│
├───Tudors S04
│       Tudors S04e08.pdf
│
├───Tutti pazzi per amore s3
│       Tutti pazzi per amore s3e15-16.pdf
│
├───Tutto Pu‗ Succedere S01
│       Tutto Pu‗ Succedere S01e01-02.pdf
│
├───Twin Peaks s1
│       Twin Peaks s1e1-8.pdf
│
├───Twin Peaks s2
│       Twin Peaks s2e16-22.pdf
│
├───Tyrant S02
│       Tyrant S02e07.pdf
│
├───Tyrant.S01
│       Tyrant.S01e01_02.720p.DLMux.pdf
│
├───Una Mamma Imperfetta S02
│       Una Mamma Imperfetta S02e01-13.pdf
│
├───Under the Dome S02
│       Under the Dome S02e02 Versione 720p.pdf
│
└───Under.the.Dome.S03
        Under.the.Dome.S03E07.HDTV.x264.SUB.ITA.pdf
```

This code would be much simpler if the file name before the "S" delimiter can not have digits. This solution assumes that there are not exclamation-marks `!` in the file names.

Comment: You are very close to what I aske, your solution is good but incomplete. Look my example list: script conflicts if is present some unrecognized files - it doesn't work for example if are present files names like http://pastebin.com/xzSnJab6. BUT script *it works*, instead, if I have this files http://pastebin.com/1mi7TKKe ***Pic*** http://i.imgur.com/JxSHLia.png . You can see that it reorganize sucessfully. **BUT** A mixed file names in folder like this http://pastebin.com/utp02Qrz is not processed by your script because something part of your code it prevents its execution, locking it.

Comment: If I have some files out of your regex *check-in* the script will not start either. Why do not process anyway if the other filenames are correctly detected?
Another example: In this file list http://pastebin.com/gNunY729 only The_Good_Wife_S06e15.pdf are moved in The_Good_Wife_S06 generated folder by script NOT other files. But if I remove to have only this files http://pastebin.com/TT2kM9FC script *works* ! Some file name BLOCK your regex recognition because in your code some elements is missing and thus prevents proper execution, blocking its action.

Comment: If you read my answer again, you may note this phrase: _"... is possible that a solution based on the example data will not work on real data"_. Nor your question neither "my specifications" indicate what to do when a file name does NOT have the given `headS##Etail.pdf` format! What my code does in this case? Simple: it fails. It is not necessary to do multiple tests to prove this obvious point. What the code should do in such a case? Well, if you give the _specification_ of what to do in this case, I will gladly modify my code accordingly...

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: In our communication it is important to have a common base in order to avoid confusions. When "only the The_Good_Wife_S06e15.pdf file is moved", your list of files have a wrong order. The files are processed in the order of `dir` command, so The_Good_Wife_S06e15.pdf and ...S06e22.pdf are the first two files and TOCCO_ANGELO_4.pdf is the third file. This means that my code _always_ process the files until the first one with bad format appear (I don't understand what "unrecognized files" means). Also, do not use terms that don't appear in my answer, like "my regex _check-in_"...

Comment: mmm.. I'm starting to understand. Can you fix your code including such specifications my filenames list showed in my examples for extending format `headS##Etail.pdf` ? But..is possible to bypass your condition *This means that my code always process the files until the first one with bad format appear* avoiding to stop scripting if a bad format appears ? *The files are processed in the order of dir command*..ok, but why don't to bypass bad format and go on scripting anyway *good format* that we are after ? Thanks, sorry for my english

Comment: **P.S:** in my filenames list examples I need to an improvement of your solution format `headS##Etail.pdf`. 
Maybe there are cases with the letter `s` and the letter `e` and that perhaps we have not yet considered and maybe some of the file name might help you. The important thing is to overcome your condition *until the first one with bad format appear*. It is frustrating a code that stops ..

Comment: I need a _specification_ (= what to do) in order to modify my code! Plase, answer this question: what you want my program do when a name without the `headS##Etail.pdf` format appear? Leave it as is? Move it to a given folder? Delete it? Explode the computer? Any other? I am sorry, but I am not a mind reader... ("Modify your code" is _not_ a specification).

Comment: I need to process any files inside a folder that your script can process. *When* a name without the `headS##Etail.pdf` format appear your script must go on to search all possible files that could be do same thing (*what is this?* moving files in folders following your code solution)

Comment: Excuse me, but you have not answered the question "What to do with the bad named file?" yet. Perhaps "nothing" would be a good answer... (You should realize that _all files_ in a folder are processed one by one).

Comment: ok.. 
try to understand me..your code when it encounters a bad format, stops and this is good BUT there are between some of these files.. missing good format filenames! - if you look carefully my lists it could still processing other files, instead, because there are still good format filename. Not everything that is bad is a bad format.The problem is not only the format `headS##Etail.pdf` , but it is linked to the fact that your script runs following an alphabetical order not controlling ALL filenames.

Comment: After several requests of specifications of what to do with bad named files and get not a clear answer, I added the specification: "Ignore files with bad names". I edited my answer in order to add the _new_ specification and modify the code accordingly; this means that my answer is now a complete solution to the question as it is stated...

Comment: thank you.. can you add also this unprocessed files, please?http://pastebin.com/fETdhg7N I need to include also `stagione` like *Stagione 3* or *Stagione 1-3*, `5x01` without `s` like *Awkward.5x01_04.pdf* or *Awkward 1x03*. Letter `S`,`s`,`E`,`e` seems have some conditions ? I try to understand what I can improve your regex but i can find where i can edit.. **However, I accept your answer, Antonio**.

Comment: So its supposed to process `name #x##` and `name S#E#` and `name S#` files??

Comment: @loadingnow: If you read the specifications, you'll realize that this code process `name1 S##E name2.pdf` files only...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the last instance of a regex substring is to break the string into chunks and process the chunks in reverse order.

```
:: A script for grouping PDF files based on book series name
:: http://i.imgur.com/seh6p.gif

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

:: Main Directory Containing PDF Directories (change this to suit your needs)
set "source_dir=.\test"

:: Move to source dir and process each folder, one at a time.
pushd "%source_dir%"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d') do (
    call :getSeriesName "%%A" series_name

    mkdir !series_name! 2>nul

    REM If you want to do additional cleanup, change the copy to a move
    copy "%%A\*.pdf" !series_name! >nul
)

popd
exit /b

::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Extracts the series name from the directory and changes spaces to periods
:: 
:: Arguments: %1 - The original book release name
::            %2 - The variable that will contain the returned value because
::                 batch doesn't actually have functions
:: Returns:   The series name and volume number
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:getSeriesName
:: Convert spaces to periods
set "raw_name=%~1"
set standard_name=!raw_name: =.!

:: Split the folder name into period-delimited tokens
set token_counter=0
:name_split
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=.-" %%B in ("!standard_name!") do (
    set name_part[!token_counter!]=%%B
    set standard_name=%%C
    set /a token_counter+=1
    goto :name_split
)

:: Get the volume number
for /l %%B in (0,1,!token_counter!) do (
    echo !name_part[%%B]!|findstr /R /C:"[sS][0-9][0-9]*[eE][0-9][0-9]*" >nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        set /a name_end=%%B-1
        set volume_value=!name_part[%%B]!
        set volume_value=!volume_value:~0,3!
    )
)

:: Rebuild the series name
set "extracted_name="
for /l %%B in (0,1,!name_end!) do set "extracted_name=!extracted_name!!name_part[%%B]!."
set extracted_name=!extracted_name!!volume_value!

:: Purge the name_part array
for /l %%B in (0,1,!token_counter!) do set "name_part[%%B]="

:: Return the extracted name
set "%~2=!extracted_name!"
```

Comment: I set for path `set "source_dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\A\"` for path and then I press .bat but it return me *The system cannot find the file specified*. Your solution is strange because I have different empty folders with `.pdf` files inside parent folder, for example i have a folder called `Alfred Hitchcock` but your script it creates a new folder called `alfred`. Why ? What is your intention ? Solution Aacini is what I expect. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user3520363 - Why would you have an `Alfred Hitchcock` folder? Are you saying that you have subfolders inside of subfolders? That doesn't match your original description. I intended for you to have each single episode to be in its own folder in the main directory and for each episode directory to include the SxxExx number because _that's what you described._ You said nothing at all about subdirectories.

Comment: @user3520363 - For reference, my script takes [this](http://imgur.com/3I4bSB9) and turns it into [this](http://imgur.com/8po6Ljh).

Comment: mmm.. I expected like your 2nd picture http://imgur.com/8po6Ljh. Your script don't start. I change your script so http://pastebin.com/meMuN6Z4. But it don't execute. Problem is simply: in *C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2* I have this  example file names list http://pastebin.com/GnwSvGtF. Well, I double-click *.bat* contains your script but nothing happens. The script will not start either. Is there any parameter so i need to start with cmd? P.S: I have not files in each folder, 
Are the files that need to be processed, the folders must be generated based on the file name, sorry

Comment: Ohhh, you have all of the single files in the same directory. Yeah, I'd need to completely rewrite my script for that.

Comment: It is still not too late to take 50 points. Look Aacini answer and my last request from comments.

Comment: Nah, I'll keep my script up for people who are in the situation that you _should_ be in instead of the one that you _are_ in. Seriously, scene naming standards exist for a reason and I'm appalled that you aren't renaming the single files you collected to conform to them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: you're right, but if I were to rename following the script would not get what I try to have. I understand come meet .. But .. is not what I want because I'm interested in the strength of the solution because I do not keep to myself the answers, but serve to people of different species that do not have time to understand what is behind, but just like that they get what they ask for, though, I accept your point of view. `Nice to meet you`.