# Fix moving and consolidating folders when use batch file process

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have this code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "SPLITCHAR=-"  & rem // (a single character to split the file names)
set "SEARCHSTR=_"  & rem // (a certain string to be replaced by another)
set "REPLACSTR= "  & rem // (a string to replace all found search strings)
set "OVERWRITE="   & rem // (set to non-empty value to force overwriting)

rem // Get file location and pattern from command line arguments:
set "LOCATION=%~1" & rem // (directory to move the processed files into)
set "PATTERNS=%~2" & rem // (file pattern; match all files if empty)

rem /* Prepare overwrite flag (if defined, set to character forbidden
rem    in file names; this affects later check for file existence): */
if defined OVERWRITE set "OVERWRITE=|"
rem // Continue only if target location is given:
if defined LOCATION (
    rem // Create target location (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%LOCATION%"
    rem /* Loop through all files matching the given pattern
    rem    in the current working directory: */
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "%PATTERNS%"') do (
        rem // Process each file in a sub-routine:
        call :PROCESS "%%F" "%LOCATION%" "%SPLITCHAR%" "%SEARCHSTR%" "%REPLACSTR%"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
rem // Retrieve first argument of sub-routine:
set "FILE=%~1"
rem // Split name at (first) split character and get portion in front:
for /F "delims=%~3" %%E in ("%~1") do (
    rem // Append a split character to partial name:
    set "FOLDER=%%E%~3"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Right-trim partial name:
if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4%~3=!"
set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~3=!"
rem /* Check whether partial name is not empty
rem    (could happen if name began with split character): */
if defined FOLDER (
    rem // Replace every search string with another:
    if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4=%~5!"
    rem // Create sub-directory (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    rem /* Check if target file already exists; if overwrite flag is
    rem    set (to an invalid character), the target cannot exist: */
    if not exist "%~2\!FOLDER!\!FILE!%OVERWRITE%" (
        rem // Move file finally (surpress `1 file(s) moved.` message):
        1> nul move /Y "!FILE!" "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

I use Command Prompt in this way to create folders and move files inside from folder1 to folder2

```
cd /D "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\"

"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test1\build-folder-hierarchy.bat" "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test2" "*.mkv"
```

**What is the problem ?**
[image: https://i.imgur.com/5ZY6RbB.png]

But I want to get a folder consolidation from files moving, not generates same number of folders from files

```
The.Race.Corsa.Mortale.2019.S1E02.Episodio2.HDTV.AAC.iTA.X264-ARSENAL.mkv
The.Race.Corsa.Mortale.2019.S1E01.Episodio1.HDTV.AAC.iTA.X264-ARSENAL.mkv
The.Feed.1x05.Episodio.5.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi.mkv
The.Feed.1x04.Episodio.4.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi.mkv
The.Feed.1x03.Episodio.3.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi.mkv
The.Feed.1x02.Episodio.2.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi.mkv
The.Feed.1x01.Episodio.1.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi.mkv
Swamp.Thing.1x10.La.Resa.Dei.Conti.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi.mkv
Volevo.Fare.La.Rockstar.1x11.Confusione.ITA.WEBRip.x264-UBi.mkv
Volevo.Fare.La.Rockstar.1x07.Tabu.ITA.WEBRip.x264-UBi.mkv
Volevo.Fare.La.Rockstar.1x01.Buon.Compleanno.Olly.ITA.WEBRip.x264-UBi.mkv
Volevo Fare La Rockstar 1x12 La Tribu Ita Webrip x264-Ubi.mkv
Virgin.River.1x10.Finali.inattesi.720p.iTA.AAC.DLRip.x265.-.T7.mkv
Virgin.River.1x07.A.dire.il.vero.720p.iTA.AAC.DLRip.x265.-.T7.mkv
Virgin.River.1x04.Un.Cuore.Ferito.iTA.AC3.WEBMux.x264-ADE.CreW.mkv
Virgin.River.1x01.La.Vita.Continua.iTA.AC3.WEBMux.x264-ADE.CreW.mkv
Tre.Giorni.Di.Natale.1x03.Episodio.3.iTA.AC3.WEBMux.x264-ADE.CreW.mkv
Tre.Giorni.Di.Natale.1x01.Episodio.1.iTA.AC3.WEBMux.x264-ADE.CreW.mkv
```

But I want to get folders and move files in this way

```
├─The Race Corsa Mortale [folder]
│ ├─The.Feed.1x05.Episodio.5.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi [file]
│ ├─The.Feed.1x04.Episodio.4.ITA.DLMux.x264-UBi [file]
  └─ ....
├─Virgin River [folder]
│ └─Virgin.River.1x07.A.dire.il.vero.720p.iTA.AAC.DLRip.x265 [file]
:
```

[image]

I try also to use this batch script but it doesn't work: I click on in via explorer but is like disactivated (I use Windows Server 2012)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Change current directory to the one where this .bat file is located
cd "%~P0"

set "digits=0123456789"

rem Process all *.mkv files
for %%f in (*.mkv) do (

   rem Get the folder name of this file
   call :getFolder "%%f"

   rem If this file have a properly formatted name: "headS##Etail"
   if defined folder (
      rem Move the file to such folder
      if not exist "!folder!" md "!folder!"
      move "%%f" "!folder!"
   )

)
goto :EOF


:getFolder file

set "folder="
set "file=%~1"
set "head="
set "tail=%file%"

:next
   for /F "delims=%digits%" %%a in ("%tail%") do set "head=%head%%%a"
   set "tail=!file:*%head%=!"
   if not defined tail exit /B
   if /I "%head:~-1%" equ "S" goto found
   :digit
      if "!digits:%tail:~0,1%=!" equ "%digits%" goto noDigit
      set "head=%head%%tail:~0,1%"
      set "tail=%tail:~1%"
   goto digit
   :noDigit
goto next

:found
for /F "delims=Ee" %%a in ("%tail%") do set "folder=%head%%%a"
exit /B
```

I accept also Powershell solutions

EDIT: Portion of the file name that I need is that before of `S#E##`, `#x##` `.#x##`, `.#x#`, `.#x##` and similar

Comment: Why is this tagged `PowerShell` ?

Comment: @Theo, he says he will "accept a powershell solution too", I believe that is why.

Comment: At Super Sonic, the issue is you can't tell what portion of the file name is the portion you want to use to name the directory, and what portion is the part you want to name the file. The best option might be to use the digits of the season, but you may have names with number sin them.  The second script is trying to do this method.

Comment: @BenPersonick Ah, my bad. didn't read that last line..

Comment: @BenPersonick Portion of the file name that I need is that before of `S#E##`, .`#x##`, `.#x#`, `.#x##` and similar

Comment: @BenPersonick your code is only a piece, not full ? I try execute your code but nothing happens, files are not moved in test2 folder

Comment: Hm... the first script [reminds me of something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39529287), and the second one seems [to have come from there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40004643)... Anyway, your situation is not exactly the same as one of those of the linked questions... How exactly do you want to split the file names? According to your description, your first example file should result in `The Race Corsa Mortale 2019`, but you stated it should be `The Race Corsa Mortale` (with `2019` removed); so what is correct, and how to precisely determine what to split off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the following script (please consult all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~1"    & rem /* (target directory; `.` is current working directory, `%~dp0.` is
                     rem     parent of this script, `%~1` is first command line argument) */
set _MASKS="*.mkv" & rem // (space-separated list of quoted file patterns)
set _SEPS=" " "."  & rem // (space-separated list of quoted separators)
rem /* Specify multiple `findstr` search strings, including the prefix `/C:`, as you would
rem    directly state them at the `findstr` command, which are used to match the particular
rem    sub-strings of the file names that are used to find the part where to split them at
rem    and to derive the name of the sub-directory where to move the respective file to: */
set _FILTERS=/C:"^S[0123456789][0123456789]*E[0123456789][0123456789]*$" ^
              /C:"^[0123456789][0123456789]*x[0123456789][0123456789]*$"

rem // Change into root directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through all matching files:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S %%_MASKS%%') do (
        rem // Store current file name and extension, initialise some auxiliary variables:
        set "NAME=%%~nF" & set "EXT=%%~xF" & set "SDIR= " & set "FLAG=#"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!` (also later on):
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Replace all predefined separators by spaces:
        for %%S in (!_SEPS!) do set "NAME=!NAME:%%~S= !"
        rem // Loop through all space-separated (quoted) items of the file name:
        for %%I in ("!NAME: =" "!") do (
            rem // Skip the loop body when a sub-string has already been found before:
            if defined FLAG (
                rem // Store current portion of the file name:
                endlocal & set "ITEM=%%~I"
                rem // Use `findstr` to match against the predefined sub-strings:
                cmd /V /C echo(!ITEM!| > nul findstr /R /I %_FILTERS% && (
                    rem // Match encountered, hence skip this and the remaining items:
                    set "FLAG="
                ) || (
                    rem /* No match found, so append the current item to the name of the
                    rem    sub-directory where the file is supposed to be moved then: */
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    for /F "delims=" %%E in ("!SDIR!!ITEM! ") do (
                        endlocal & set "SDIR=%%E"
                    )
                )
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        rem // Process only file naes where sub-directory names could be derived from:
        if not defined FLAG if not "!SDIR:~1,-1!"=="" (
            rem // Create sub-directory, if not yet existing:
            ECHO 2> nul mkdir "!SDIR:~1,-1!"
            rem // Move current file into the sub-directory (but do not overwrite in case):
            ECHO if not exist "!SDIR:~1,-1!\!NAME!!EXT!" > nul move "!NAME!!EXT!" "!SDIR:~1,-1!\"
        )
        endlocal
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Supposing the script is called `consolidate.bat` and the target directory is `%UserProfile%\Downloads`, call the script like this:

```cmd
consolidate.bat "%UserProfile%\Downloads"
```

After having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands** in front of the `mkdir` and `move` commands!

Comment: I test your script but it creates folders correctly but files are not moved inside in the respective folders. I replace `ECHO 2> nul mkdir` into `2> nul mkdir "!SDIR:~1,-1!"` and `ECHO if not exist "!NAME!!EXT!" move` into `if not exist "!NAME!!EXT!" move`. Script is called consolidate.bat, and is it in *C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test1*. Files are in the same path of script.

Comment: In the command prompt I type `cd C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test1`, then `consolidate.bat "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test1"`: folders are created but files are not move inside them. `S#E##`, .`#x##`, .`#x#`, .`#x##` are examples of separator like The.Feed.1x04.. , The.Feed.S1x04..., The.Feed.S1x04.,, The.Feed.S1E04...,The.Feed.1x4.

Comment: Oops, sorry, there was a small mistake, `if exist` looked at the wrong location...

Comment: For filenames as *Pippi Calze Lunghe Ep 01 - Villa Villa Colle* I try to set filter as `/C:"^Ep [0123456789][0123456789]*$" ^` but don't work. How include a blank space ?

Comment: The _space_ is used to separate the parts of the file names, so `Ep` and `01` are separate parts; however, I would simply specify `/C:"^Ep$"` as the search expression since `Ep` should not occur in the title part anyway, I guess/hope...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we can split the file name on the Digits in the name, this should do the needful.

I put a pause in, inspect the output and make sure that it is giving you the right info before clicking enter.

```
@(SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  REM SET "_SrcFolder=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test1"
  REM SET "_DstFolder=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\test2"
  REM SET "FileGlob=*.mkv"
  SET "_SrcFolder=C:\Admin"
  SET "_DstFolder=C:\Admin\test2"
  SET "FileGlob=*.txt"
)
CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  FOR %%A IN (
    "%_SrcFolder%\%FileGlob%"
  ) DO (
    CALL :Process "%%~nA" "%%~xA" "%%~fA"
  )
GOTO :EOF

:Process
  SET "_OLDName=%~1"
  FOR /F "Tokens=1 Delims=0123456789" %%a IN ("%~1") DO (
    SET "_NewFolder=%%a"
  )
  SET "_NewName=!_OLDName:%_NewFolder%=!"
  ECHO._OLDName=%_OLDName%.%~2
  ECHO._NewFolder=%_NewFolder%
  ECHO._NewName=%_NewName%.%~2
  REM pause
  ECHO.
  ECHO.  We will now do the following if you press any key:
  ECHO. MD "%_DstFolder%\%_NewFolder%\"
  ECHO. COPY "%~3" "%_DstFolder%\%_NewFolder%\%_NewName%%~2"
  ECHO.

  PAUSE

  MD "%_DstFolder%\%_NewFolder%\"
  COPY "%~3" "%_DstFolder%\%_NewFolder%\%_NewName%%~2"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: After execute this script nothing happens, only appears cmd but in test2 folders I don't see nothing https://i.imgur.com/iRT6Ttk.png

Comment: your code is only a piece, not full ? I try execute your code but nothing happens, files are not moved in folders

Comment: @SuperSonic  Some mistakes in there I had to rush to a meeting, fixed it all up. and updated

Comment: @SuperSonic You never tested the updated one I posted Yesterday, it fixed the minor issues.

Comment: your script don't work. I create a .bat, copy your code and save. I click on it but files are not moved and folders are not created. Files are in the same path of script