# Batch script to create folders and move files using part of their name

Tags: batch-file

I have a file list as:

```
Pcat2.zip
Pcat3.zip
Pcat22.zip
PcatGig10.zip
PcatGig21.zip
Pcolt2ned.zip
PColt3ned.zip
PColt10ned.zip
PColtI-1.zip
PColtIII-6.zip
PcoltIII-11.zip
PcoltIII-18.zip
PcoltIV-2.zip
PetPap25.zip
Pier4.zip
Pier16.zip
ProvSegrIV-4.zip
ProvSegrIII-1.zip
AttFIII-29.zip
AttFlI-5.zip
AttFlII-20.zip
AttFlVI-18.zip
```

I tried to use a script which created directories according to a key string in file name, and move the files into them, like this:

```
|
+---Pcat
|      Pcat2.zip
|      Pcat3.zip
|      Pcat22.zip
|
+---PcatGig
|      PcatGig10.zip
|      PcatGig21.zip
|
+---Pcolt
|      Pcolt2ned.zip
|      PColt3ned.zip
|      PColt10ned.zip
|      PColtI-1.zip
|      PColtIII-6.zip
|      PcoltIII-11.zip
|      PcoltIII-18.zip
|      PcoltIV-2.zip
|
+---PetPap
|      PetPap25.zip
|
+---Pier
|      Pier4.zip
|      Pier16.zip
|
+---ProvSegr
|      ProvSegrIV-4.zip
|      ProvSegrIII-1.zip
|
+---AttF
|      AttFIII-29.zip
|
\---AttFl
       AttFlI-5.zip
       AttFlII-20.zip
       AttFlVI-18.zip
```

However, I also want to strip decimal and Roman-like numbers

```
I-5
III-6
VI-18
VI-18
III-29
...
```

To accomplish that I tried this script, but it doesn't work.
I take a look here
[Implement Regex in batch or powershell script to generate folders and move files in relative folders ordered by key string in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520085/implement-regex-in-batch-or-powershell-script-to-generate-folders-and-move-files)

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "SPLITCHAR=-"  & rem // (a single character to split the file names)
set "SEARCHSTR=_"  & rem // (a certain string to be replaced by another)
set "REPLACSTR= "  & rem // (a string to replace all found search strings)
set "OVERWRITE="   & rem // (set to non-empty value to force overwriting)

rem // Get file location and pattern from command line arguments:
set "LOCATION=%~1" & rem // (directory to move the processed files into)
set "PATTERNS=%~2" & rem // (file pattern; match all files if empty)

rem /* Prepare overwrite flag (if defined, set to character forbidden
rem    in file names; this affects later check for file existence): */
if defined OVERWRITE set "OVERWRITE=|"
rem // Continue only if target location is given:
if defined LOCATION (
    rem // Create target location (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%LOCATION%"
    rem /* Loop through all files matching the given pattern
    rem    in the current working directory: */
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "%PATTERNS%"') do (
        rem // Process each file in a sub-routine:
        call :PROCESS "%%F" "%LOCATION%" "%SPLITCHAR%" "%SEARCHSTR%" "%REPLACSTR%"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
rem // Retrieve first argument of sub-routine:
set "FILE=%~1"
rem // Split name at (first) split character and get portion in front:
for /F "delims=%~3" %%E in ("%~1") do (
    rem // Append a split character to partial name:
    set "FOLDER=%%E%~3"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Right-trim partial name:
if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4%~3=!"
set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~3=!"
rem /* Check whether partial name is not empty
rem    (could happen if name began with split character): */
if defined FOLDER (
    rem // Replace every search string with another:
    if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4=%~5!"
    rem // Create sub-directory (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    rem /* Check if target file already exists; if overwrite flag is
    rem    set (to an invalid character), the target cannot exist: */
    if not exist "%~2\!FOLDER!\!FILE!%OVERWRITE%" (
        rem // Move file finally (surpress `1 file(s) moved.` message):
        1> nul move /Y "!FILE!" "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

The script requires the directory containing all the files to process as the first command line argument. The created sub-directories are placed therein. An optional second command line argument defines a file name pattern to filter certain file types/names. Supposing it is saved as D:\Script\build-folder-hierarchy.bat, the files are contained in D:\Data, and you want to handle *.zip files only, run it as follows:

```
"C:\Script\build-folder-hierarchy.bat" "C:\Data" "*.zip"
```

Comment: I have tried to improve your question post, but in doing so, I noted an anomaly, which I was unable to accurately place in your question. The part about stripping the names and decimal and Roman numbers. Firstly many Roman numbers, e.g. `I`, `V`, `X`, `L`, `C`, `D`, and `M`, are alphabet letters, already included in your filenames as string components, and secondly, if those were removed, you would have multiple problematic name clashes. Please clarify what it is supposed to mean, and what you've currently done, in your code, to cater for it. Also 'It doesn't work' is not a useful explanation.

Comment: @Compo yes, you're right. I replace "Roman numbers" with "Roman-like numbers" because here you can't look as alphabet letters but as alphanumerical letters because in file names you can find `I-5`,
`III-6`,
`VI-18`,
`III-29`..
...

Comment: Your question specifically said strip, not replace, and your code does not appear to do either. This site does not provide code which you have not attempted yourself, it is not a free scripting/coding service. There are many places where you can contract the services of a person to provide you with coding and scripting solutions, this is, according to the guidance, not one of those. Please also debug your script, as I've already mentioned, you need to explain which part of your script, 'doesn't work', i.e. what is not working as intended, what is/isn't happening, etc.

Comment: Also, you have not answered my question, how is the script supposed to know that `PColtI`, or `ProvSegrIV` are strings, or strings concatenated with Roman numerals? Does the code need to identify every possible sequence of one or more alphabeic characters which can ever be understood as valid Roman numerals as such? or are you expecting it to have some sort of human-like AI abilities?

Comment: You would also need to clearly define the directory names you expect to be created in advance, because there has to be a mechanism to attribute, `PcatGig` string files, before `Pcat` string files, otherwise the former would be placed into the latter location, if parsed first!

Comment: @Compo, I know you are mad at me. I take this code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520085/implement-regex-in-batch-or-powershell-script-to-generate-folders-and-move-files

Comment: Of course the script from the other thread does not work because it was written for another purpose, namely to split file names at a certain character. Anyway, before beginning to write a script you need to unambiguously specify how the file names have to be treated; how to distinguish between roman numerals and the preceding textual name, whether there is always only one group of decimal numerals, whether roman numbers always appear together with decimal ones, and so on…

Comment: I know where the code came from, and I know it isn't your code. What you've done is take someone elses code, and effectively reproduce it asking others to make it do something different. You have not made any attempt at adapting it yourself for the task you now require of it. That is exactly what my previous comments have alluded to. We do not provide a free coding/scripting service. You are expected to research and adapt the code yourself, and if that adaptation fails to perform exactly as intended, create a question.

Comment: In that question you are expected to post a [mcve] of your adapted code, and in it, fully provide debugging and explanatory information for us to reproduce the single and specific issue you require assistance with. That issue cannot be that you don't know how to do it, so haven't tried. Please take the [tour], and read through all of the linked pages of [ask], to understand how this site is supposed to work to your advantage and that of our other members and future readers. I'm not mad, I'm simply trying to educate you, because you have clearly not understood the purpose of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that accomplishes the task you require (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0TEST"      & rem // (target directory containing files to process)
set "_MASK=*.zip"          & rem // (pattern to match the files against)
set "_SEP=-"               & rem // (separator between roman and decimal numbers)
set "_ROMAN=I V X L C D M" & rem // (characters that build up roman numbers)

rem // Change into the target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through all matching files:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%_MASK%"') do (
        rem // Store full file name and base name in variables:
        set "FILE=%%F" & set "NAME=%%~nF"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Split off (first) group of decimal numerals and everything after from
        rem    base name: */
        for /F "delims=0123456789 eol=0" %%E in ("_!NAME!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Store resulting file name prefix in variable:
            set "PREF=%%E"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem /* Check whether last character is the predefined separator character
            rem    between roman and decimal numbers and remove it in case; afterwards,
            rem    split off all characters that may build up a roman number: */
            set "PREF=!PREF:*_=!"
            if defined PREF if "!PREF:~-1!"=="!_SEP!" (
                set "PREF=!PREF:~,-1!"
                call :ROMAN PREF PREF
            )
        )
        rem // Create sub-directory named like the retrieved file name prefix:
        2> nul md "!PREF!"
        rem // Move the currently iterated file into the sub-directory (no overwrite):
        if not exist "!PREF!\!FILE!" > nul move /Y "!FILE!" "!PREF!"
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Return from the target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B


:ROMAN
    rem // Remove roman number from the end of a provided string:
    set "#STR=%~2"
    set "#RTN=%~1"
    set "%#RTN%=!%#STR%!"
:ROMAN_LOOP
    if defined %#RTN% (
        rem /* Check whether the last character of the string is a valid roman numeral
        rem    and split it off in case: */
        set "FLAG=" & for %%R in (!_ROMAN! !_ROMAN! !_ROMAN!) do (
            if "!%#RTN%:~-1!"=="%%R" set "FLAG=#"
        )
        if defined FLAG set "%#RTN%=!%#RTN%:~,-1!" & goto :ROMAN_LOOP
    )
    exit /B
```

The following approach is implemented:

- split off everything beginning at the first numeric part from the file name;
- check whether the remainder ends with `-` which separates a roman number from a decimal one in your sample files;
- if it does remove it and remove from the end the longest sequence that consists of characters that may build a roman number without checking if it actually is a valid one;

Comment: Thank you very much. I change only `set "_ROOT=%~dp0TEST"` into set `"_ROOT=%C:\Users\Administrator\Test\"`

Answer (score 0):

The following very inefficient batch file using only internal commands of the Windows command processor works for files with names matching following conditions:

1. A roman number in file name is in range `I` to `XXXIX` (1 to 49) and the roman number is left to a hyphen and a decimal digit or left to the file extension. The roman number is interpreted case-insensitive by command **SET** on applying the substitutions.
2. The **first** decimal digit in range `0` to `9` in the file name is interpreted as character which delimits the substring to use as folder name from the remaining file name part which is ignored for the folder name.
3. Decimal digits at beginning of a file name are ignored for the folder name.
4. The wildcard pattern passed to the batch file as second argument should end with a file extension. Something like `*.*` results in processing only the files with a file extension as the first file has which is returned by the file system to the command process processing the batch file and not all files in source folder.

The batch file code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "SourceFolder=%~1"
if not defined SourceFolder set "SourceFolder=%CD%"
for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%") do set "SourceFolder=%%~fI"
if not "%SourceFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "SourceFolder=%SourceFolder%\"

set "FilePattern=%~2"
if not defined FilePattern set "FilePattern=*.zip"
for /F "tokens=* delims=?* eol=|" %%I in ("%FilePattern%") do if "%FilePattern%" == "%%I" if "%FilePattern:~0,1%" == "." (set "FilePattern=*%FilePattern%") else set "FilePattern=*.%FilePattern%"

for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%%FilePattern%") do set "FileExtension=%%~xI" & goto ProcessFiles
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo ERROR: There are no files matching the pattern !FilePattern! in folder:
echo        "!SourceFolder!"
endlocal
echo(
pause
exit /B

:ProcessFiles
pushd "%SourceFolder%" || goto :EOF
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%FilePattern%" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%J in (XXXIX XXXVIII XXXVII XXXVI XXXV XXXIV XXXIII XXXII XXXI XXX) do (
        for %%K in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J-%%K=0!"
        set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J%FileExtension%=0%FileExtension%!"
    )
    for %%J in (XXIX XXVIII XXVII XXVI XXV XXIV XXIII XXII XXI XX) do (
        for %%K in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J-%%K=0!"
        set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J%FileExtension%=0%FileExtension%!"
    )
    for %%J in (XIX XVIII XVII XVI XV XIV XIII XII XI X) do (
        for %%K in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J-%%K=0!"
        set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J%FileExtension%=0%FileExtension%!"
    )
    for %%J in (IX VIII VII VI V IV III II I) do (
        for %%K in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J-%%K=0!"
        set "FolderName=!FolderName:%%J%FileExtension%=0%FileExtension%!"
    )
    for /F "eol=| delims=0123456789" %%J in ("!FolderName!") do (
        endlocal
        set "FolderName=%%J"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    if "!FileName!" == "!FolderName!" (
        endlocal
        set "FolderName=%%~nI"
        if not defined FolderName set "FolderName=%%~xI"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    md "!FolderName!" 2>nul
    move /Y "!FileName!" "!FolderName!\" >nul
    endlocal
)
popd
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains how to reference batch file arguments as done with `%~1` and `%~2`.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.